# File upload in browser is taking very long time

Tags: windows-explorer

File upload in browser is taking very long time.

It is happening because when I try to upload a file (let's say include an attachment in mail), a File Explorer type of window appear which does not list the files immediately as it used to. In place of showing the files it shows a blank window with a message "Working on it".

In some extreme cases it goes on for a minute. It's very inconvenient and annoying.

[image: This is one such recent File Upload Dialogue. I waited for almost 30 secs to see if it shows files this time.]

Comment: Does that folder has numerous files? Check CPU and RAM usage. May be drag and drop works as an alternate.

Comment: Drag and drop works, but it's not always available. Also in case of gmail, "drag and drop" has different behaviour than file upload through File Explorer.

That folder has 77 items. Does that count as too many?

Comment: Ok let's test. Move your required file in a empty folder and then try. Is it better now?

Comment: Actually there is no need to test. Other folders which has much less files load quicker (not instantly, even in those case). The problem is that it's not acceptable speed. 77 items is nothing compared to the number of files I used to keep earlier. It always loaded almost instantly. IMO putting artificial constraint on the number of files because somewhere something is wrong is not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Steps

### Step 1

1. Go to your Folder. Right-click context menu, Click on *Properties*.
2. Properties menu select the *Customize* tab.
3. You’ll find an entry *Optimize this folder for* Make sure General Items is Selected.
4. Check the Tick box of *Also apply this template to all subfolders* Apply and OK.

### Step 2

1. Windows + R (Run) Type msconfig.
2. Go to Services Tab. Search for *Windows Search* Services.
3. Uncheck the Tick Box. Apply and OK Restart your PC.

Remember when your Rebuild the Windows Search Index. This Service should be running.

### Step 3

1. Type Memory Diagnostic in start menu.
2. Run Windows Memory Diagnostic tool. This is Desktop App in Windows 10
3. Click on Restart now and check for the problems (Recommended).

This will Restart your system. Depending on your RAM size i will take long time to complete. If any defeat its gives you report.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem. Can you please explain what the problem was?

Comment: Which step did you follow

Comment: I followed all the three steps. But I think Step 1 solved the problem as under "Optimize this folder for", Images was selected. Does Windows automatically sets this option?